# Opening PDF file using Android intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-storage

So here's the Scenario:

I am downloading a PDF from network and saving it in `/0/Download/NSIT - Notices/"fileName".pdf`

Now sending Intent like this:

```
private void openPDF(String fileName) {
    Log.d(TAG, "openPDF: called");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download", "NSIT - Notices");
    File myPDF = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/NSIT - Notices", fileName + ".pdf");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", myPDF);
    Log.d(TAG, "openPDF: intent with uri: " + uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with..."));
}
```

Now any PDF reader (Google Drive PDF Reader, System PDF Viewer) is saying

```
The File Does Not Exist
```

Image:
[image]

The Google one is sitting not doing anything (that's why not included its image)

```
Mainfest.xml

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

Provider_path.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I am creating File here in AsyncTask but opening from the postExecute of that AsyncTask

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download", "NSIT - Notices");
            File myPDF = new File(myDir, params[1] + ".pdf");
            if (!myDir.exists())
                myDir.mkdirs();
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myPDF);
                fileOutputStream.write(response.bodyAsBytes());
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Download complete");
```

Logcat

[image]

Previously it was throwing `FileUriExposedException` then I fixed with this `FileProvider` thing. The problem is the pdf file downloaded by my app is created successfully and I am able to open it successfully from any File Manager (ES File Explorer now) but not from my app :(. I am new to `FileProvider`. Need help!

PS: That's not my device problem either. Tested with two other phones which has different ROMs and API >= 23

Comment: i think it has to do something with FileProvider

Comment: set this before startActivity `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Comment: I have tried this before I implemented FileProvider to overcome FileUriExposedException. No help. But Now implemented File Provider and added this intent flag. Wokring now. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @Sunny Post answer, I will accept it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your welcome good to see it works :)

Comment: Please don't forget to catch `ActivityNotFoundException` which is thrown if no application to open PDF is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please set `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

It will grant access of your file to other providers

Answer (score -1):

See documentation for [File provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element)

> Whether the content provider is available for other applications to use:
>
> true: The provider is available to other applications. Any application
> can use the provider's content URI to access it, subject to the
> permissions specified for the provider.
>
> false: The provider is not available to other applications.
> access to the provider to your applications. Only applications that
> have the same user ID (UID) as the provider will have access to it.

Try to change android:exported="true"

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported